# Adding objects with duplicate tags in Cocos2D

Tags: cocoa, tags, cocos2d-iphone, parent

I'm trying to remove a child from a CCLayer and then immediately re-add it.

```
[player setTag:kPlayerSpriteTag];
[self addChild:player];
[[self getChildByTag:kPlayerSpriteTag] removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES]; 
[self addChild:player];
```

However, this crashes with the error: "child already added. It can't be added again"

Am I failing to remove the child from the CCLayer correctly?

Comment: remove it directly from parent(in this case self); sorry for short answer im actually cocos2d-x guy!you can do this by passing child pinter to self removiechild(or somthing like this)

Comment: This code is possibly dangerous, in between removing the player and adding it again it may be deallocated if it is not retained elsewhere.

Comment: the code for adding the player works fine. my problem is with removing the child...

Answer (score 0):

The only possible explanation I can find to this is that you have duplicated tags in your node tree.

In this case, `[self getChildByTag:kPlayerSpriteTag]` will just return the first node that has `getChildByTag:kPlayerSpriteTag`, which could possibly be different than `player`.

If you use tags to retrieve nodes, you should ensure they are unique.

Comment: in other words, you mean that: `[self getChildByTag:kPlayerSpriteTag] == player`... is this true?

Comment: yep. so [player removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES] seems to remove the parent-child relationship, but  [[self getChildByTag:kPlayerSpriteTag] removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES] does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    [self removeChildByTag:101 cleanup:YES];
```